# Adjust long press of back button to kill app in CM7?

Tags: cyanogenmod

As you may know, CM7 has this nice feature where you can hold down the Back button to kill a misbehaving app (Settings > Applications > Development > Stop app via long-press).

Unfortunately this feature kills apps too quickly for my taste; I find myself killing apps that I didn't intend to kill at least a couple of times a day. Mostly this is a mere inconvenience, but I fear that at some point I'll corrupt some file by accidentally quitting an app that's writing to it.

Is it possible, perhaps through some hidden settings file, to adjust how long the long-press for this button must be? I'd like to at least double it.

Answer (score 1):

I have not ever found a way in any the settings to adjust this. I think the time is hard coded. I completely agree with you about the time before it would close, for this reason, I disable it unless I am testing something and need it for a specific test.